# Make a tableView that shows previous user inputs (in other views)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm stack doing my first app, I searched a lot of tutorials about tableviews, arrays and segues but I can't even figure it out how to resolve my problem, here I go:

I need that the app store a value in an array (class) so I can access it latter (not in the next segue), I did a different app more simple than the last one, just with a UITextfield input and a button to add it to the class. When I move from the user input part to the tableView, the tableView is empty. I will put the code here:

```swift
TABLE VIEWCONTROLLER


      import UIKit

    class NameTableViewController: UITableViewController {
        var names = [Name]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            }

     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return names.count

        }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cellIdentifier = "NameTableViewCell"
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? NameTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("The dequeueReusable cell is not an instance of NameTableViewCell")
            }

            let name = names[indexPath.row]

            cell.nameLabel.text = name.name


            return cell
        }



USER INTERFACE VIEWCONTROLLER:





    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var name = [Name]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func addingButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       let writtenName = nameTextField.text ?? "No name written"
      let name1 = Name(name: writtenName)
       name.append(name1)
    }

}

<!-- end snippet -->





VIEWCELL:





    class NameTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

<!-- end snippet -->

NAME CLASS METHOD:

    class Name {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
       self.name = name
    }

}
!-- end snippet -->
```

[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77BcN.png)

[User Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLkMy.png)

Sorry if this is a dumb question, as you may have notice I'm new programming and swift is the first language that I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **nsuserdefaults**  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults and store a key decodable struct and later on call it everywhere.

// Save Data

```
struct People: Codable {
    let name: String?
}

var peopleArray = [People]()
let mike =  People(name: "mike")
peopleArray.append(mike)

UserDefaults.standard.set(peopleArray, forKey: "people")
```

// Request Stored Data

```
func getPeople() -> [People]?{

    let myPeople = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "people")
    if myPeople == nil {
        return nil
    }
    let peopleArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([People].self, from: myPeople!)
    return peopleArray

}

let people = getPeople()

if(people != nil){
   for person in people {
     print(person.name)
   }
}
```

Comment: Since this is Swift, you should post a link to `UserDefaults`, not `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry for that. but the solution is written in Swift just made a mistake on the URL. I'll update it thanks for the observation.